# Angular2 assign active class to the li tag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I would like to assign the active class to the li tag in angular2 but am stuck.

This is what i have tried

```
<li  [class.active]="  _router.isRouteActive(_router.generate(['/dashboard']))" > 

     //the above _router.isRouteActive throws an error

  <a routerLink="/dashboard">
   <i class="icon-display4 position-left"></i> Dashboard</a>
 </li>
```

IN my ts file i have

```
export class SecondaryNavComponent implements OnInit {

  //thinking of using to determine active link

 constructor(public _router:Router) { }  //tried also with private

 ngOnInit() {
 }
```

}

THe error reads

```
ERROR TypeError: co._router.generate is not a function

ALse webstorm generates an error that
unkwon method router is active
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the RouterLinkActive directive for this:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

It's already inside the `@angular/router` package.

Comment: THe routerLink active directive sets active class on the a tag but not on the outer li

Comment: It can also set the active class on an ancestor of a routerLink, read the class description section with the examples

Comment: thanks i see on the part with ..............Finally, you can apply the RouterLinkActive directive to an ancestor of a RouterLink.